# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, cuda

I'm setting up a CUDA development environment but it is being challenging...
I installed Visual Studio Professional with x64 compiler tools, CUDA SDK and Notebook Dev Drivers, all 64bit. Also I'm using windows 7 Pro 64bit.

When I try to compile anything it gives the error on the title:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'

Already tried to put this file in the same folder as the .cu and it just asks for more libs. When I put all the libs it asks, it gives another strange error...

Any Help?

Comment: What is the error it gives when you put all the libs?

Comment: none now :S it just started to work! Maybe a reboot was missing or something... But still, on my classes I didn't have theses libs in the .cu file... do you have any idea what may cause that?

Comment: Tutorials on setting up VS 2010 and CUDA: http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/03/using-cuda-and-thrust-with-visual-studio-2010/ and http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/02/24/how-to-run-cuda-in-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Setting up VS2010 and cuda on http://cuda.nu (Turkish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just followed this post http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/02/24/how-to-run-cuda-in-visual-studio-2010/